# Google sheet : Create unique ID based on timestamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I tried to follow up on a tutorial to create a unique ID based on a timestamp from a google form in a google sheet.
However, I tried a few things and not a single one works.

I would like some advice on what I do wrong to improve myself.

I tried to have id start at B1 and follow the line 1

I used this :

```
={"Inquiry_id"; Arrayformula(if(len(B4:4), "INQ"&text(row(B1:1)-1, "000"),))}
```

Here is a picture of the current situation:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks a lot

Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
={"Inquiry_id", Arrayformula(if(len(B4:4), "INQ"&text(COLUMN(B1:1)-1, "000"),))}
```

assuming your row delimiters are commas (,)

otherwise for French settings:

```
={"Inquiry_id"\ Arrayformula(if(len(B4:4); "INQ"&text(COLUMN(B1:1)-1; "000");))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's ! But saddly still getting #ERREUR! as result

Comment: I was wondering, maybe it's not coming from the formula but as misconfiguration on my sheet ?

Comment: Maybe, but first try this ={"Inquiry_id"\ Arrayformula(if(len(B4:4); "INQ"&text(COLUMN(B1:1)-1; "000");))} which is what I get if I change setting to France.

Comment: Tom, it's work ! Thank you, you spotted correctly it was due to the French setting. Really appreciate your taking the time! I wish you a beautiful day, best regards from France!

Comment: Merci beaucoup!